# Minikube stuck while starting cluster components

Tags: macos, kubernetes, minikube

I am running `minikube` on OSX(10.11.6). The MiniKube version is `v0.32.0`. I tried `minikube start` and `minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox` but nothing happened. `minikube logs` returns following ending lines:

```
 "default" not found' (will not retry!)
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.041218    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.141908    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.242425    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.342554    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.356554    2753 event.go:203] Server rejected event '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"minikube.1575b26407cfea35", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"default", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil), Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Initializers:(*v1.Initializers)(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:""}, InvolvedObject:v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"minikube", UID:"minikube", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}, Reason:"NodeHasNoDiskPressure", Message:"Node minikube status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure", Source:v1.EventSource{Component:"kubelet", Host:"minikube"}, FirstTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xbf02edc36dd8a835, ext:304052783, loc:(*time.Location)(0x65b5120)}}, LastTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xbf02edc379932901, ext:500824829, loc:(*time.Location)(0x65b5120)}}, Count:4, Type:"Normal", EventTime:v1.MicroTime{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, Series:(*v1.EventSeries)(nil), Action:"", Related:(*v1.ObjectReference)(nil), ReportingController:"", ReportingInstance:""}': 'namespaces "default" not found' (will not retry!)
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.443704    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.543821    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.644184    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.744680    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.846014    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:28 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:28.946588    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.047233    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.147681    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.249598    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.350486    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.452012    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.552799    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.653338    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.754054    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.810125    2753 eviction_manager.go:243] eviction manager: failed to get get summary stats: failed to get node info: node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.854208    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:29 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:29.954427    2753 kubelet.go:2236] node "minikube" not found
Jan 01 10:23:30 minikube kubelet[2753]: I0101 10:23:30.054224    2753 kubelet_node_status.go:73] Successfully registered node minikube
Jan 01 10:23:58 minikube kubelet[2753]: I0101 10:23:58.148416    2753 reconciler.go:207] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "default-token-tp92s" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/secret/595d2631-0daf-11e9-a450-080027367c5d-default-token-tp92s") pod "kubernetes-dashboard-5bff5f8fb8-dn2cl" (UID: "595d2631-0daf-11e9-a450-080027367c5d")
Jan 01 10:23:58 minikube kubelet[2753]: E0101 10:23:58.154023    2753 reflector.go:134] object-"kube-system"/"default-token-tp92s": Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets "default-token-tp92s" is forbidden: User "system:node:minikube" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
Jan 01 10:23:58 minikube kubelet[2753]: I0101 10:23:58.259886    2753 reconciler.go:207] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "tmp" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/host-path/596ca5da-0daf-11e9-a450-080027367c5d-tmp") pod "storage-provisioner" (UID: "596ca5da-0daf-11e9-a450-080027367c5d")
Jan 01 10:23:58 minikube kubelet[2753]: I0101 10:23:58.260040    2753 reconciler.go:207] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "storage-provisioner-token-z445r" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/secret/596ca5da-0daf-11e9-a450-080027367c5d-storage-provisioner-token-z445r") pod "storage-provisioner" (UID: "596ca5da-0daf-11e9-a450-080027367c5d")
Jan 01 10:23:58 minikube kubelet[2753]: W0101 10:23:58.375518    2753 container.go:406] Failed to get RecentStats("/system.slice/run-rc6cb56d0426945b89d61a0f99b9dda20.scope") while determining the next housekeeping: unable to find data in memory cache
```

Comment: I've gotten this before as well, and while I don't know what causes it, running `minikube delete` followed by `minikube start` fixes it for me.

Comment: @GrantDavidBachman I did it various time and did not work. Eventually I used an older version < `0.26`

Comment: Are you using VPN?  Known issue with no known workaround: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3503.