# Minikube start stuck in waiting for pods and timeout

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I try to run a sample application in my Ubuntu 18 vm.

I have installed Docker client and server version of 18.06.1-ce. I already have VirtualBox running.

I use below link and install kubectl 1.14 too: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux

I have Minikube v1.0.1 also installed. But Minikube start command stuck in Waiting for pods: apiserver and timeout

```
harshana@-Virtual-Machine:~$ sudo minikube start
  minikube v1.0.1 on linux (amd64)
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.14.1 images in the background ...

⚠️  Ignoring --vm-driver=virtualbox, as the existing "minikube" VM was created using the none driver.
⚠️  To switch drivers, you may create a new VM using `minikube start -p <name> --vm-driver=virtualbox`
⚠️  Alternatively, you may delete the existing VM using `minikube delete -p minikube`

  Restarting existing none VM for "minikube" ...
⌛  Waiting for SSH access ...
  "minikube" IP address is xxx.xxx.x.xxx
  Configuring Docker as the container runtime ...
  Version of container runtime is 18.06.1-ce
⌛  Waiting for image downloads to complete ...
✨  Preparing Kubernetes environment ...
  Downloading kubeadm v1.14.1
  Downloading kubelet v1.14.1
  Pulling images required by Kubernetes v1.14.1 ...
  Relaunching Kubernetes v1.14.1 using kubeadm ... 
⌛  Waiting for pods: apiserver
```

sudo minikube logs:

```
May 19 08:11:40 harshana-Virtual-Machine kubelet[10572]: E0519 08:11:40.825465   10572 kubelet.go:2244] node "minikube" not found
May 19 08:11:40 harshana-Virtual-Machine kubelet[10572]: E0519 08:11:40.895848   10572 reflector.go:126] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://localhost:8443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%!D(MISSING)minikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: What do you get for `sudo minikube logs`?

Comment: Great, that will give you something to search for.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994643/minikube-stuck-while-starting-cluster-components) seems to agree with golchi's answer.

Comment: I had a problem with the Minikube tutorial recently, and I found that [the illustrated settings are not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55800654/472495).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same behaviour because I have created a first VM using kvm. I have followed the instructions and deleted the VM. Run the below :

```
1- minikube delete -p minikube
2- minikube start
```

Comment: Actually i dont see any minikube in virtualbox. Any way when i ran it gave,  Failed to delete cluster: exit status 1

Comment: I think the default settings for a new `minikube start` is to use the VirtualBox driver. Since the question author wants to use Docker, that should be `sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none` at minimum. As per my link under the question, I found that a `--extra-config` was required too.

Comment: @halfer i try with --extra-config as in other post but not worked. Anyway i create a ec2 instance and install kubectl 1.11 with minikube 1.0. Then i use sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none and i get [ERROR NumCPU]: the number of available CPUs 1 is less than the required 2. The free tier gives me instance with 1 cpu. How can i get rid of this error

Comment: @Harshana: you can search for that error using a search engine, do please let me know what you find. I believe there is a fix for it, but really it is telling you that you need two CPUs - perhaps it does not run well if you only have one.